# Remove top-N layers from a pretrained model and Save as new model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can I remove certain layers AND be able to save it as a new model in tensorflow?

I have the following code for removing top-N layers in tensorflow and it works:

```
reconstructed_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
embedding = Model(reconstructed_model.input,
              reconstructed_model.layers[-4].output)
```

However, when I am trying to save it with either of these two methods:

```
tf.keras.models.save_model(model=embedding, model_path)

embedding.save(model_path)
```

I am encountering the following error:

```
KeyError: "Failed to add concrete function 'b'__inference_model_3_layer_call_fn_286241'' to object-based SavedModel as it captures tensor <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=resource, value=<Resource Tensor>> which is unsupported or not reachable from root. One reason could be that a stateful object or a variable that the function depends on is not assigned to an attribute of the serialized trackable object (see SaveTest.test_captures_unreachable_variable)."
```

The pretrained model that I am using is a fine-tuned efficientnetv2 from the tensorflow applications api

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
```

and I was able to save and reuse it here, just don't know how to save a modified one after reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `EfficientNetB0` and constructed a model truncating the last four layers, just as you did.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
import tensorflow as tf

efficientnet = EfficientNetB0( include_top=False )
embedding = tf.keras.models.Model(
     efficientnet.input ,
     efficientnet.layers[ -4 ].output
)
embedding.summary()
embedding.save( 'embedding_model.h5' )
```

And then loading the model, using `tf.keras.models.load_model`,

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model( 'embedding_model.h5' )
model.summary()
```

I could load the model without any problems. Maybe there's some problem with the `reconstructed_model`.